# how can i end the programm if the array is full? MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data 
array: .space 40
message1: .asciiz "Enter a number ~> "
message2: .asciiz "The max number is ~> "
.text
.globl main
main: 

la $t0 , array
li $t1, 0 
li $s0 , 0 
move $s1 , $v0

loop:       
    addi $v0 , $0 , 4
    la $a0 , message1 
    syscall 

    addi $v0 , $0 , 5
    syscall     
    sw $v0 , 0($t0)

    addi $t5 , $t5 , 4    
    addi $s0 , $s0 , 1    
    beq $s0 , $s1 , max 

    j loop

max:     
    la $t0 , array #load array start address    
    lw $t2 , 0($t0) #max = first element    
    li $s0 , 0 #i == 0

max_loop:     
    lw $t3, 0($t0) #temp = actual array element    
    slt $t4 , $t2 , $t3 #max < temp ?    
    bne $t4 , 1 , else     
    move $t2 , $t3 #max = temp 

else : 
    addi $s0 , $s0 , 1    
    addi $t6 , $t5 , 4    
    beq $s0 , $s1 , exit

j max_loop

exit: 
    addi $v0 , $0 , 4 
    la $a0 , message2 
    syscall 

    li $v0 , 1 
    move $a0 , $t2
    syscall
```

Comment: Can you reason how to do it in C or other language?  It'll work the same in assembly.

Comment: FYI, you need to single step debug this.  Examine what each instruction is supposed to do vs. what it actually does.  Look at the effects each instruction has on the registers and on memory.  You should see problems right away.

Comment: i just lost it in the process.  i had to clear up my mind and look at it again. Anyway thanks for the tip!